# С3863: Тип массива char[64] является неоднозначным

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char text[64];

    text = argv[1];

    cout << text << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Примитивная программа, при компилировании которой выходит две ошибки:

E0137: Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением
C3863: Тип массива char[64] является неоднозначным

Comment: Попытка присвоить массиву указатель в строке `text = argv[1];` явно ни к чему. Может вы собирались копировать строку? `strcpy` там, а еще надо проверить, что аргументов действительно  хотя бы 2

Comment: Именно это я и хотел сделать

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше уж так:

```
char * text;
text = argv[1];
cout << text << endl;
```

Зачем вам копировать куда-то строку?

Чтобы копировать, нужно убедиться, что выделено достаточное количество памяти, использовать `strcpy` или `strcpy_s`...

Проще - раз у вас С++ - использовать `string`:

```
string text;
text = argv[1];
cout << text << endl;
```

P.S. И, кстати, ошибка выглядит не так, как написали вы - *C3863: Тип массива char[64] является* **неоднозначным**, а *C3863: тип массива "char [64]" является неназначаемым*. Согласитесь, неназначаемый и неоднозначный - несколько разные вещи :)

Comment: Извините за ошибку. И к слову, мне нужно было выделить именно недостаточное количество памяти, так или иначе, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @WhateverWhateverovich, для копирования строки в динамическую память прекрасно подходит функция [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)